# JQuery Test HTML Content of Class/Conditionally Set CSS of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs with the class "eac-item".

Some of the items have content - but others are "blank" and only come up with this:

```
<div class="eac-item"><br></div>
```

What would the syntax be in JQuery to add a CSS property of "display:hidden" to those specific items?

```
if($('.eac-item').html() == "<br>") { {$(this).hide } ...?
```

How do you handle the syntax for this type of function?

Comment: `display: hidden` is an invalid CSS property. Do you mean `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should do the trick

```
$(".eac-item").each(function(){
  if ($(this).html() == "<br>")
    $(this).hide();
});
```

but i would suggest to go with below approach

```
 $(".eac-item").each(function(){
      if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "")
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to hide the elements (add `display: none`) would be iterate through every `.eac-item` using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
$('.eac-item').filter(function(index) {
  // Filter all elements whose only child is a <br>
  return $("*", this).length === 1 && $("br", this).length === 1;
}).each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.eac-item { border: 2px #000 solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="eac-item">
  <br>
</div>

<div class="eac-item">This is not hidden.</div>
```

You might want to use [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) instead of `hide()`, if you're really trying to remove the element from DOM.